# Graphviz: How can I create edges between HTML table cells?

Tags: graphviz

Please consider the following code:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext]

    a [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                           <TR><TD ID="first" BGCOLOR="gray">first</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD ID="second" PORT="f1">second</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD ID="third" PORT="f2">third</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>>];

    b [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                           <TR><TD ID="first" BGCOLOR="gray">first</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD ID="second" PORT="f1">second</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD ID="third" PORT="f2">third</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>>];

    a:first -> b:first;
}
```

I get a fair amount of warnings:

```
laci@nitehawk ~ $ dot records.gv -T pdf > records.pdf
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
in label of node a
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
Warning: Illegal attribute ID in <TD> - ignored
in label of node b
Warning: node a, port first unrecognized
Warning: node b, port first unrecognized
```

1. According to the [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) the ID attribute of TD should be legal.  What am I missing?
2. How can I reference individual cells and create edges between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `PORT` instead of `ID` and then use the edge definition as in your example.

```
<TD PORT="first" BGCOLOR="gray">first</TD>
```

[`ID`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:id)'s purpose is *downstream use*, so unless you're using SVG output and reuse the id's elsewhere, they are probably not really useful.

As to the warnings, I do not get them with graphviz 2.28. If you use an older version of graphviz, I suggest to update.

[image: graphviz html label ports]

Answer (score 17):

For completeness sake here's the full source that actually works:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext]

    a [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                           <TR><TD PORT="c" BGCOLOR="gray">first</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT="d">second</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT="e">third</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>>];

    b [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                           <TR><TD PORT="c" BGCOLOR="gray">first</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT="d">second</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT="e">third</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>>];

    a:c -> b:c;
}
```

Comment: Good on you for posting the complete solution.  Makes life much easier for those of us who stumble upon this question.