# Graphviz: How can I make the style of an HTML table cell bold?

Tags: graphviz

I'd expect the following dot code to make the title bold but the `<b>` tag doesn't seem to be working in this context for some reason.

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=plaintext]

    a [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
                           <tr><td><b>title</b></td></tr>
                           <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
                           <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
              </table>>];
}
```

Any working alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact graph actually does work. You'll most certainly need to update graphviz.

Here's the output with 2.28:

[image: bold graphviz title]

Comment: Thank you, installing 2.28 did the trick, indeed.  I wouldn't have ever assumed that Ubuntu's Graphviz is 3 years old! - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/+bug/673021

Comment: That should also get rid of the [warnings in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13369992/63733).